# regexp in bash (downloading output form regexp)

Tags: regex, bash

I have got a file that look like:

```
<a href="some-adress">some-txt</a>
<a href="some-adress">some-txt</a>
<a href="some-adress">some-txt</a>
...
```

I need to download all files that are as "some-adress", how can I do that using only bash?

Comment: What do you mean "only bash"? Bash can't do it (easily). You will need some sort of utilities such as those in the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use wget ? It already have that feature :

```
wget -i --force-html yourfile.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do that using a combination of `sed`, `xargs`, and `wget`:

```
sed -n 's/.*<a href="\([^"]*\)">.*/\1/p' input-file | xargs wget
```

Comment: Couple tweaks:  you might want to change [^"]* to [^"]\+ to ensure the pattern appears at least once, and you might want to use xargs -n 1 so xargs will be called once for each address.

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f 2 -d '"' file-with-addresses.txt
```

[`cut`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html#top) is included in all posix shells. This command will split the line using the `"` as the delimiter and return the second "field". To download using wget Adam Rosenfield's method is fine.

```
cut -f 2 -d '"' file-with-addresses.txt | xargs wget
```